# High response time in WSO2 DSS

Tags: sql, oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a simple data service using WSO2 DSS for the following simple query.

"SELECT * FROM EMP_VIEW"

"EMP_VIEW" is having around 45 columns and 8500 entries(tuples). My DB instance is Oracle 11g Enterprise edition & i'm using ojdbc6.jar as the driver. Due to some reason Data Service takes around **14 mins** to get the response once I try it in SoapUI. 
But the same query takes around **14 or less seconds** to retrieve all the records in Oracle SQL Developer/ Eclipse database explorer.

Any idea why it's taking high response time?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but potential direction in order to get to an answer.

There may be multiple factors at play here. You have proven that the Oracle side is working well (assuming the 14s response time is acceptable).

You mention that SOAPUI takes considerable time. This could be a SOAPUI problem where it is waiting for all results to be returned (time taken) and then building a full display (more time taken) before showing the full result.

The Oracle Dev tool could be faster at showing results since it may not be; waiting for the full result set and/or taking much time to build the display.

Keep in mind that DSS is taking the SQL result and placing XML, that in itself may add some time but I suspect the SOAPUI tool is taking a significant amount of time to decode the XML and place on your screen.

To further narrow down the problem I suggest you use another tool
1. possibly the TRYIT tool from DSS and see what type of timing it gets for the same calls.
2. write a small client c# / java etc and measure that actual time between your request and the response. This will definitely tell you how long DSS is taking versus how long it takes for the client to form a display.

Please do post your results as this type of information is definitely helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandings and observations, SOAP UI waits till whole message receive. therefore that much of time will spent. but when you try curl, you can find less seconds to generate the response.

I tried curl to receive 2MB messages with streaming enabled DSS service, 
The response was generated within less than one second.